# Responsive website design - mobile first

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am building my first responsive website using the mobile first approach. I have all my elements in a one-column design. I have a lot of hidden images and elements that only become visible as the screen size increases.

I am technically still loading all these images and other hidden elements on a mobile device, even though they aren't visible. Is there a way to not load images on mobile devices, and only load them on larger screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS3 media queries, it is up to the device whether or not the images are loaded. Most devices are smart enough to only load images for the screen size they have.

If you want to guarantee that images only load on larger screens, you should [use JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/08/combining_media.html) and you can set the `src` attribute of the image elements, when `document.documentElement.clientWidth` reaches a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using ASP.NET (Server Side):

On the server side you can use this code:

Lets take the example of ASP.NET

```
if(!Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice) { // if not a mobile
  // show the images!
}
```

For More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.ismobiledevice(v=vs.110).aspx

The only advantage of the server-side as compared to the client side, is that server won't bother sending the images if the screen side is short! But the client side would download and not show. So, use server-side if it was my bet!

#### Using jQuery:

And on the client-side. You can use many ways, first way is the jQuery

```
if($(window).width >= 'value') {
  // show the images 
}
```

For More: http://api.jquery.com/width/ (jQuery width)

#### Using media query:

```
@media screen only and (min-width: 700px) { // if min width is 700px
  // show the images
}
```

These are some of the methods which can be used in this scenario!

For More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript plugin for that.
This script will only load the image according to its current viewport.

Sourcecode:
https://github.com/kvendrik/responsive-images.js

Tutorial:
http://davidwalsh.name/responsive-design